IMAX B6 batt charger- force to charge when low voltage/connection break
The Imax B6 battery charger refuses to charge batteries when they are below certain values, and it is highly recommended and safer for users.
However, certain times I need to force the load and accept the risk with personal monitoring and control. Is it possible to configure Imax to skips checks and the Imax "CONNECTION BREAK" error message?
As workaround for "problematic" Li-Ion (3.6 V) batteries I was able to to increase its voltage through charging them pretending that they are:
Li-Fe (3.3 V).
NiCd (1.2V) ( when Li-fe option was refusing to charge)
Note1: After charging the batteries with the minimum required I was able to continue as Li-Ion
Are there better alternatives than lying to the charger  about the tech to charge with lower voltage?
How bad/risky is to apply a process for NiCd/NiMH to a Li-Ion batt?
Note2: Lithium batteries have a much higher risk of thermal runaway; that can cause really dangerous situations; than other types of chemistries as lead-acid, Ni-Mh,... So, be careful when restoring, or recycling batteries

How much is your house worth? A lot? Then don't circumvent that safety feature.

I always do and suggest to do these type of actions under supervision. These safety controls are good for people without basis on electricity. But IMO users of this forum can go further ;)

OK, I'll go further: I was hired to do a post-mortem on a $ 2 M yacht that burned because the Li-ion cells were over-discharged and then recharged. One of the Li-ion cells  caught fire while recharging overnight, a few days later. Luckily. the yacht was moored and no one was on board. You say "under supervision". Do you plan to personally supervise your battery continuously from now on, so you can catch the moment it starts a thermal runaway?

Thanks for the real example. Do they check each cell during the "recovery" after over discharge?  Probably the wrong cell had values that indicated the replacement. During the process I dispose cells and reuse those ones that passed the check. Then I use for personal projects and i charge these batteries/projects on safe spaces without combustible materials as plastics, wood or paper above or near.

"Do they check each cell". "They" don't. The BMS does.
